# Запись 2D массива в файл в Си

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется функция, которая должна записывать содержимое матрицы в файл в текстовом формате:

```
void save_game(int **matrix){
     FILE *file;
     char name[50];
     printf("Save the game: ");
     scanf(" %s", &name);

     file = fopen(name, "w");

     int row_size = sizeof(matrix)+1;
     int column_size = sizeof(matrix[0])+1;
     //print_board(matrix);
     fwrite(matrix, sizeof(int), row_size*column_size, file);
     fclose(file);
}
```

После вызова функции в новосозданном файле появляется нечитаемый мусор. При этом, с самим содержимым матрицы всё хорошо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как сделать это правильно?

EDIT: Матрица динамическая, в каждой ячейке находятся целые числа(int) от 0 до 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое. Как выглядит матрица, которую вы передаете? как

```
int matrix[N][M];
```

или создается динамически, т.е имеем массив указателей на массивы, так что рассматривать матрицу как один кусок памяти никак нельзя.

Но это не так важно, хотя бы потому, что

```
sizeof(matrix)
```

это размер указателя - т.е. обычно 4 (8) байт в зависимости от архитектуры.
Как и

```
sizeof(matrix[0])
```

каковой у вас точно такой же размер указателя...

И пишете вы не пойми что (какой вид имеет матрица?) в размере, скажем, 4*4*5 = 80 байт...

Если вы покажете, **что** вы передаете в функцию - можно поговорить о том, **как** записывать правильно.

**Update**

Если я вас верно понял, то у вас что-то типа

```
int ** matrix = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    matrix[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(int));

// Заполнение матрицы
```

то передавать нужно и размеры:

```
save_game(matrix,N,M);
```

а писать примерно так:

```
void save_game(int **matrix, int N, int M)
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        fwrite(matrix[i],sizeof(int),M,file);
```

Ну, или - если нужен текстовый вывод -

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            fprintf(file,"%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        fprintf(file,"\n");
    }
```

Comment: Матрица динамическая, в каждой ячейке находятся целые числа(int) от 0 до 9. Буду очень благодарен, если объясните, как правильно указывать размеры матрицы.

Comment: Передавать как параметры функции, и записывать в файл циклом по строкам.

Comment: В этом случае в файле оказывается куча невидимых символов. При попытке написать это через двойной цикл с fprintf(file, "%c", matrix[i][j]+'0') внутри, выдаёт segmentation fault.

Comment: Неважно. fprintf заработал. Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Сто-стоп-стоп! У вас *хоть раз* упоминалось, что вывод должен быть **текстовым**? У вас был неверно написанный **бинарный** вывод, который я и исправил. По применению `fwrite`я даже представить не мог, что вы пытаетесь использовать ее для *текстового* вывода... 8-\

Comment: Извиняюсь, я действительно не упомянул про формат. Мне он казался очевидным.

Comment: @Arden: На SO нет "неважно" и "мне казался очевидным". Вопросы и ответы здесь пишутся не для вас, а для будущих читателей. Это значит, что все детали вопроса должны быть указаны в самом вопросе. Исправляете ваш вопрос прямо сейчас. Перенесите туда все отсутствующие детали.

Answer (score 0):

```
void save_game(int **matrix, int rows, int columns){
     FILE *file;
     char name[50];
     printf("Save file name: ");
     scanf(" %s", &name);

     file = fopen(name, "w");
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){  
            fprintf(file, "%c", matrix[i][j]+'0');
            if(j != columns-1) fprintf(file, " ");
        }
        if(i != rows-1) fprintf(file, "\n");
     }
     fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Что это и как это связано с исходным вопросом? Почему вдруг формат записи поменялся на текстовый?

Comment: Да и как только числа будут не однозначными цифрами, код перестанет работать.